# Using a loose array just to specify the object properties

Tags: javascript

I'm using this array to specify the properties I want to operate on. I didn't use `for..in` because there's a property that doesn't follow the same pattern.

```
const data = {};

[
  'teaching_levels',
  'axes',
  'accessibility_resources',
  'contents',
  'resources',
].forEach((name) => {
  data[name] = {
    options: results[name],
    values: req.query[name],
  };
});

// This property is different
data.licenses = results.licenses;
```

Is it alright to have an array like that?

Comment: I'd like to hear what makes you (OP) think this might not be okay. Any specific concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, yes, definitely. That saves a lot of manual code writing and makes it easier to change in the event you need to change all of them.

The only difference I would probably make is, add your *different* properties when you create the object, that will not only slightly improve speed, but will also make the code a tiny bit smaller.

```
const data = {
    licenses: results.licenses
};

[
  'teaching_levels',
  'axes',
  'accessibility_resources',
  'contents',
  'resources',
].forEach(name => data[name] = {
    options: results[name],
    values: req.query[name],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I would consider something like this:

```
const data = {
    teaching_levels: null,
    axes: null,
    accessibility_resources: null,
    contents: null,
    resources: null,
    licenses: results.license,
    decorateResults: function () {
        Object.keys(this).forEach( (prop) => { 
            if (this[prop] === null) {
                this[prop] = {
                    options: results[prop],
                    values: req.query[prop]
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
data.decorateResults();
```

To me this helps make the data model for `data` more clear. And decouples the operations of data model definition from data population/decoration more clearly.  The init() function could, for example, be an external function. If you want even more decoupling, you could simply pass the data structure to the decorator function, rather than having the decorator function living on the object.

Comment: Will it be safe to call this function more than once? (Is it idempotent?) I think, it's not, so I'd prefer this function *not* to be a part of the object itself, and also name it the way it highlights the fact it is unsafe to call many times. Alternatively, return a new object with the decorated fields, but this changes the way function is used, which may not be desired. So, I like the original code/bear-wrestler's answer better.

Comment: ^ I thought about this initially as well. I think if I were to use this a quick one-off, adding `delete this.decorateResults;` to the end of the method would suffice.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko This is idempotent as you are only writing keys where current property state is null.  This state would not exist once initial saturation has occurred.

Comment: @mike you're right. I overlooked the null check.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce yes, it would work too, and do the same thing, yet looks dirty solution to me. Similarly, I'm not a big fan of in-place state changes generally, but that's preferential and I don't know the OP's context.